# send/receive messages to/from MSN messenger with php?

Tags: php, msn

i wonder if one can integrate php with MSN messenger.

so eg. if one send a message to a "php" account the php could fetch the message and return a message to the messenger.

is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for **[PHP MSN Messenger Class](http://flumpcakes.co.uk/php/msn-messenger)** :)

Comment: @fayer: I have never come upon such need to implement msg messenger but you can try that out.